# Unset namespace from Current-context

Tags: kubernetes

I have set the namespace to current context like below

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=ns1
```

I tried to unset the namespace from current context , but it didn't work.

I am looking for help, Could you please share me the command to unset the namespace to default .

Answer (score 18):

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=default
```

or

```
kubectl config unset contexts.name-or-your-current-context.namespace
```

Both will result in usage of the default namespace for the current context.

Comment: Thanks Fritz, I am curious to check , if I unset the namespace, whether It will not set back to default.

Comment: I see. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, if this worked for you, please flag my answer as correct for the sake of the community.

Comment: actually, no.. `unset` of namespace means to "remove" the namespace key from your kubeconfig, not necessarily setting it back to default. no...

Comment: @p01ntbl4nk you are right about that. However, once no namespace is set for a context, the "default" namespace will be used, right?

Comment: It seems to clear the value of the namespace when you don't pass a value try `[$]> kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=` to clear the namespace.